# XML schema using Swagger editor

Tags: xml, schema, swagger

I have an question about XML schema on Swagger Editor.

I tried to create an element like below, but it have failed.

```
<CompanyName Code='1' CodeContext='context'>example</CompanyName>
```

i try using that on swagger Editor:

```
CompanyName:
 xml:
   name: CompanyName 
 enum: [example]

 properties:
  Code:
    type: string
    enum: [1]
    xml:
      attribute: true
  CodeContext:
    type: string
    enum: [context]
    xml:
      attribute: true
```

But the out was :

```
<CompanyName>example</CompanyName>
```

the attributes does not appears

What's wrong with that?

Comment: What exactly 'has failed'?

Comment: @Heri the result that appears is:

     <CompanyName>example</CompanyName>

Comment: Sorry. If you want us to understand your problem you have to explain what you did, what you expect, etc. "the result that appears": Do you really think anybody understands that? Where did it appear? After which action?

Comment: @Heri i'm sorry, i have edited the question trying to be more specific!

Comment: Looks better now. But since I do not know swagger Editor I cannot help you. Sorry.